# Websphere administrative console greyed out

Tags: eclipse, websphere-7

I am new to websphere. I am following an internal guide to setup my workstation. So I've created a profile, and then created the server using the profile, and now I need to run the administrative console.

But I can't because `Administration > Run Administrative Console` is greyed out.

What causes this ? How can I make it work ?

Comment: can you clarify what "the option" is that's greyed out?  Perhaps provide an image?

Comment: In general you need to start the server to access the console. And provide more info to what option you are referring to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you are referring to option in RAD/Eclipse in the `Server view`.

You first need to start the server, then the option will be enabled. You can start the server from the `Server view` also.

To start server manually from command line, go to `PROFILE_ROOT\bin` and execute `startServer serverName` (usually server1).

To access console, just open browser and use `http://localhost:9060/ibm/console` assuming default ports.